# wrapfigure misplaced

Tags: floats, positioning, wrapfigure

I have this code:

```
\chapter{Experimenteller Teil}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.2\linewidth}
  %\centering
  \includegraphics{image.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindtext
```

and I get this:
[image: as you can see, the picture is misplaced]

as you can see, the picture is misplaced, but if I use multiple wrapfigure, all of them are placed at the right position, if I end the previous line (`\\`), except the last, which is placed on the margin again. I tried actual text instead of blindtext but same result.

I used scrreprt as document class.

EDIT: Minimal not-working example:

```
\documentclass
[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openany
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter}
  {
    \blindtext \\
    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.2\linewidth}
      %\centering
      \includegraphics{image.pdf}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext \\

    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.2\linewidth}
      %\centering
      \includegraphics{image.pdf}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext \\
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not know why it causes this, but if you remove the blank line after `blindtext \\`  the code behaves differently, and the image moves in the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, `[width=\linewidth]` was not the solution. I fixed it now by adding a empty line after the chapter:

```
\documentclass
[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openany
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter}
  {
    \blindtext \\
    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.2\linewidth}
      %\centering
      \includegraphics{image.pdf}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext \\

    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.2\linewidth}
      %\centering
      \includegraphics{image.pdf}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext \\

    %↑ this empty line was necessary to fix it, could someone explain?
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove the brackets `{ ... }` around your chapter, it behaves the same with or without the additionnal line ...

Comment: ok, I see, but why?

Comment: The thing is that I do not think that using `\\` inside the corpse of the document is a good practice... If someone else can back me up on this, feel free to do so.

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph (latex would have warned abount this: underfull box of 10000 (maximum) badness.

Comment: please use `example-image` as your test image (and adjust the dummy text  to ensure that the problem occurs with that image, otherwise no one else can see the issue. the wrapfig documentaion does warn that there are restrictions of you use it in a group, which explains why you need a blank line if you have a group there but why do you have the chapter text in a group?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple remarks here.

I personally never used `\blindtext` so I replaced it with `lipsum` calls instead, and I removed the multiple `\\` which don't seem appropriate (personal opinion here !).

So that anybody can compile your document I would adivse using `example-image-a` to obtain an example image, which is provided by the `graphicx` package (see the code below).

Finally, to address your question, if you add `[width=\linewidth]` to you `includegraphics` calls, the size of the image is derived from the width of the `wrapfigure` which avoids trespassing the margins or the text.

Working code

```
\documentclass
[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  openany
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter}

    \lipsum[1] 
    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\linewidth}
      %\centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1] 

    \begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\linewidth}
      %\centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.pdf}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1]
    \lipsum[1] 

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: well, you could use https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF2mN.png

Comment: Not sure I understand you comment... Does my answer address your problem ?

Comment: I misunderstood that you asked for an image. Anyway, this seems not to help. this example works, but not if I used it in my actual code. I try to figure it out and answer again later.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but this was not the solution. Bu I found a solution, but do not understand it, see below.